# Creating a class in c++ that is accessible by its members

Tags: c++

I am trying to define a hexagonal grid for a simulation. I am using cube coordinates, as illustrated here: https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#neighbors-axial. I am trying to make it so that each coordinate, being three of them, is part of the naming of the class specific object. For example, let us look at the origin. I have a class holding each of the three coordinates, along with some other data. I want this object to be called hex(0,0,0) such that each zero is related to the three coordinates defined by the class. 
ie;

```cpp
class hex{
     int r_coordinate: 
     int g_coordinate;
     int b_coordinate;
     metadata
     ...
}

hex hex(-2,1,1)={
     r_coordinate=-2;
     g_coordinate= 1;
     b_coordinate= 1;
     metadata
     ...
}
```

Comment: Your variable names cannot contain `-`

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @eike but I am still struggling with the actual question at hand.

Comment: Do you want to organise many hexes? Like in an multidmensional map? Why don't you just name it `hex_0_0_0` or something like that? It's not entirely clear what you mean.

Comment: Variable names also cannot contain `(`, `,`, or `)`.  And then the key question is, do you want to do this as code generation or are you envisioning some kind of run-time mapping between variable values and names? (The latter would reflection which is always a problem in c++ where "variable name" is not by default a run-time concept.)

Comment: @SantanaScott your question is not very clear to me. Do you want an object actually called `hex(0,0,0)` or do you want to be able to create any hex object with r,g and b values (e.g. `hex some_object(0,0,0)`)?

Comment: @ churill The problem with naming it hex_0_0_0 is that these values aren't dynamically accessible. Im trying to create a system so that I can take the values in the name of the object, such as hex_0_0_0, and add the constants 2, -1, -1 so that I get the object hex_2_-1_-1.

Comment: In bog-standard, deafult environments c++ variables names does't "exist" at run-time. For instance, debuggers require the names to be supplied through some additional channel (though many executable formats support such a channel). Perhaps you could back out  a layer or two and explain the problem you are trying to solve instead of the mechanism you envisioned?

Comment: I want to have a tile system made using the three coordinates. Mostly I need to take a hexagon, use its coordinates, and be able to do arithmetic to it's coordinates from there. Such as transformations and rotations. The reason I want the coordinates to be in the object name is so that i'm not just naming the hexagons "hex_1", "hex_2"... and so forth.

Comment: What you want is essentially impossible, because varaible names can't contain a -. So hex_2_-1_-1 is no legal variable name. However I can't think of any scenario where you could need this. Please explain why you think, you need such a thing.

Comment: @Sata I'm going to take a wild guess that, perhaps, you are very new to programming. In that case you may not be familair or comforatable with the notion of acting on *collections* of data objects. You probably don't need to give each tile that you create it's own name, you need to create and act on colelctions of tiles (presumably stuck into some kind of container object like a `std::vector` or something similar). If this is the case, you're probably better off with a good tutorial and/or a mentor you can sit with in person than posting to Stack Overflow before you know the *right questions*.

Comment: "The reason I want the coordinates to be in the object name is so that m not just naming the hexagons "hex_1", "hex_2"... and so forth" - So you expect to have variable name that actually changes with it's value? There is no reason for that, you give a variable a name that describes what it does. Like `originHex = hex(0,0,0)` and such.

Comment: @dmckee churill I don't think I can explain my question well enough over text. Thank you for your help nevertheless

Comment: I think what you want is neiver doable nor useful. And I think that you are trying to solve a XY-problem here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create objects of class `hex` and want to specify the RGB values during creation, what you need is a [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) (maybe someone edit this for a better reference):

```
class hex {
    public:
        hex(int r, int g, int b)
        : r_coordinate(r), g_coordinate(g), b_coordinate(b)
        {
        }
    private:
        int r_coordinate;
        int g_coordinate;
        int b_coordinate;
};

hex x(1,2,3); // x.r_coordinate == 1, x.g_coordinate == 2, x.b_coordinate == 3
```

I am not sure if this is what you are after.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question at all.

Comment: @sweenish Well, OPs question does not seem very clear to me and the "name" of his hex object looks like an initialization. I am definitely not sure if this is what OP wants, but it's the closest C++ code I could imagine.

Comment: They want the coordinates in the name of the object. It does look like an initialization, but the description gets the point across okay enough. My thing is I don't quite understand why this is wanted at all. If it's for debugging, that's what debuggers are for.

Comment: @sweenish thank you for understanding. I should have made it more obvious I was trying to write pseudocode. I am trying to make a system like this so I can take on object, for example, hex_-3_2_1 and obtain the information -3, 2, 1 and I can do arithmetic on them.

Comment: thank you @eike—knowing it can't really be done is helpful.

Comment: If you tell us the reason, you want to obtain information based on object names, maybe we can give you a different solution for that problem.